# Swift Double Tap Recognizer Responding To A Single Tap Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a weird problem with my app; when I add a single tap recognizer to a Label, it works fine:

```
private func addDoubleTabGestureRecognizerToWordLabel(){
    wordLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked(gesture:)))
    
    
    wordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    
    
}
```

or

```
private func addDoubleTabGestureRecognizerToWordLabel(){
    wordLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked(gesture:)))
    
    
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    
    
    wordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    
    
}
```

But when when I change the tap number to something else like so,

```
private func addDoubleTabGestureRecognizerToWordLabel(){
    wordLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked(gesture:)))
    
    
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    
    
    wordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    
    
}
```

I get this error on tapping the label:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PolyLibrum.WordLabel showInfoAroundWordLabelWhenTabbed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdea951b2d0'
```

Even more strange is the fact that the error gets triggered when I tap the label once and not twice.

Here's the selector function:

```
@objc func labelClicked(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("UILabel clicked")
    
    
    //executed when the label is double tapped
    //worked when I set the gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    
    let bubbleFrame = wordLabel.frame;
    let translationBubble = TranslationBubble(frame: bubbleFrame)
    
    wordFrame.addSubview(translationBubble as! UIImageView)
}
```

Why does the recognizer get triggered on a single tap instead of a double tap? And what does the selector function have to do with the number of taps required to trigger it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Search your project for the word "showInfoAroundWordLabelWhenTabbed", especially in the storyboard/XIB files. There's probably something that triggers that selector when you single-tap the label, not knowing that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because of some mismanagement the tap gesture is not able to add for that recognizer. You may not need to send the gesture to the selector function.

Change this

```swift
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked(gesture:)))
```

To

```swift
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked))
```

in `addDoubleTabGestureRecognizerToWordLabel()`

and remove the receiving parameter in `labelClicked()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, but it did clean up my code a lot. The 'gesture' argument really was redundant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to delete an interface-builder-gesture-recognizer I was experimenting with previously as Sweeper said in his/her comment. Everything worked when I removed the element. Thanks again for all your answers.